# convergence in $L^1$ for product of functions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, integration, lp-spaces

If $f_n$ converges to $f$ in $L^1$ and $g_n$ converges to $g$ in $L^1$. Does it necessarily mean that $f_ng_n$ converges to $fg$ in $L^1$ for finite measure spaces.

Comment: No, to begin with, $fg$ need not be in $L^1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Did already pointed out, $f \cdot g$ and $f_n \cdot g_n$ are in general not integrable, therefore we need stronger assumptions. Using the ($L^1$-)triangle inequality and Hölder's inequality, it's not difficult to prove the following result:

> Let $f_n \to f$ in $L^2$ and $g_n \to g$ in $L^2$. Then $f_n \cdot g_n \to f \cdot g$ in $L^1$.

Comment: Is it the $L^1$-triangular inequality? $\|f_ng_n-fg\|_{L^1}=\|(f_n-f)g_n+f(g_n-g)\|_{L^1}\le \|(f_n-f)g_n\|_{L^1}+\|f(g_n-g)\|_{L^1}\le\| f_n-f\|_{L^2}\| g_n\|_L^2+\|f\|_{L^2}\|g_n-g\|_{L^2}$

Comment: @roi_saumon Your reasoning is fine, though it's Hölder's inequality which you need (rather than the triangle inequality in $L^1$)

Comment: Yes, for the last step. But what did you have in mind with $L^2$-triangular inequality?

Comment: @roi_saumon Ah, that's what you meant. Yes, you are right, it's the $L^1$-triangle inequality which one needs to use.

Answer (score 1):

Of course not. Consider the Lebesgue measure on [0,1] and the functions $f_{n}=g
_{n}=\frac{1}{x^{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n}}}$ for $n>1$