# Counterexample of $X_{n}$ and $Y_{n}$ converging in $L^{1}$ but not their product

Tags: probability-theory

Could someone give me an example where $X_{n}$ and $Y_{n}$ converge in $L^{1}$ but $X_{n}Y_{n}$ doesn't converge in $L^{1}$?

Comment: See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/529483/631742

Comment: Do you know any examples of pairs of functions $X,Y$ in $L^1$ whose product is not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$X_n = Y_n = \chi_{[0,1]} x^{-1/2}$.